# Прием и отправка сообщений (файлов)

Tags: java, javafx

Доброго времени суток!
Задача такая , нужно принимать и отправлять сообщения , а затем их красиво отображать , например как в приложениях VK для телефона или Skype. Для отображения сообщений я буду использовать LitVeiw , который будет использовать коллекцию CollectionMessage объектов Message . В классе Message будет метод , который будет принимать сообщения и добавлять их в коллекцию от пользователя и Отравителя сообщений(из сети) .  Я слышал , что для работы с сообщениями нужно изучать JavaEE  и JMS или можно обойтись без этого .

Comment: Куда именно отправлять и откуда принимать вы планируете?

Comment: планируется месенджер сообщений ,  отправлять пользователю по сети и принимать  , вообщем .что то похожее на Skype

Comment: Тогда можно взять готовый JMS-сервер. Или разработать свой протокол и написать свой сервер на сокетах.